# Problem executing SQL query in Zend?

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

I was executing sql query in zend something like this and it was working:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
$resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('db');
$dbAdapter = $resource->getDbAdapter();
$statement = $dbAdapter->query("SELECT * from tablename");
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

At that time my **application.ini** was something like this:

```
resources.db.adapter = "Mysqli"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "username"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"
```

**Question:**

Now I changed my **application.ini** to:

```
resources.multidb.local.adapter = "Mysqli"
resources.multidb.local.host = "localhost"
resources.multidb.local.username = "username"
resources.multidb.local.password = "passwod"
resources.multidb.local.dbname = "dbname"
resources.multidb.local.default = true
```

Now above zend code is producing following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getDbAdapter() on a non-object in Mapper.php  on line 297
```

How to fix my code according to new **application.ini** settings ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: http://jaybill.com/2007/09/12/using-the-zend-framework-with-multiple-databases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the default Database Adapter use the following code:

```
$bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
$resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('multidb');
$db = $resource->getDb();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me with multidb configuration in **application.ini**

```
$bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
$resource = $bootstrap->getPluginResource('multidb');
$db = $resource->getDb();
$statement = $db->query("SELECT * from tablename");
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```